# PROLOG-number of positive and negative numbers

Tags: prolog

I received the following task that must be solved in the PROLOG. We have list of positive  and negative numbers and variables `P` and `N`. The variable `P` must contain a number of positive numbers in list, and variable `N` must contain a number of negative numbers. The part that I made works well if all the numbers in the list are positive, but then it crashes. Can somebody help me? Thanks

```
   numbers([],0,0).
   numbers([G|R],P,N):-
      numbers(R,NR,NN),
      P is NR+1,
      G>0.
   numbers([G|R],P,N):-
      numbers(R,NR,NN),
      N is NN+1,
      G<0.
   numbers([],P,N).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. A common Prolog idiom is the use of *helper predicates* and *accumulators*:

```
count_by_sign( Xs , P , N ) :- count_by_sign( Xs , 0 , 0 , P , N ) .

count_by_sign( [] , P , N , P, N ) .
count_by_sign( [X|Xs] , A , B , P , N ) :-
  tick(X,A,B,A1,B1) ,
  count_by_sign(Xs,A1,B1,P,N)
  .

tick( X , P , N , P  , N1 ) :- % negative numbers
  X < 0 ,
  N1 is N+1
  .
tick( X , P , N , P1 , N  ) :- % positive numbers
  X > 0 ,
  P1 is P+1
  .
tick( X , P , N , P  , N  ) :- % zero is unsigned
  X = 0
  .
```

Answer (score 3):

First, the base case : when a list is empty, no numbers

```
numbers([], 0, 0).
```

Now, for the general case

```
numbers([H|T], X, Y) :-
    % you compute the rest of the list
    numbers(T, X1, Y1),
    % you increment the correct number
    (H > 0
    -> X is X1 + 1, Y1 = Y
    ;  H < 0
    ->  X = X1, Y is Y1+1
    ;   X = X1, Y1 = Y).
```

EDIT I fix the case of 0

Answer (score 1):

here is how it can be done with library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)):

```
numbers(L,P,N) :-
  aggregate(t(sum(P),sum(N)),
    X^(member(X,L), (X > 0 -> P=1,N=0 ; X < 0 -> P=0,N=1)), t(P,N)).
```

test:

```
?- numbers([3,-1,4,0,-4,1],P,N).
P = 3,
N = 2.
```